# Git/Gerrit Jenkins Continous Integration: How to handle rebase needs

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

I have a question regarding continuous integration with Jenkins for Git/Gerrit: is there any way to cancel Jenkins job execution when the Git change needs a rebase/merge due to previous change has been accepted during the waiting period?

Best Regards,

Comment: if gerrit cannot automerge then the change should be reviewed and also verified. So I would not skip it. and I think this can not be skipped since the job triggers on 'Patchset created' and in this case a merge/rebase is a new patchset

Comment: Hi HiB, I mean quitting from current Jenkins build job execution when a rebase/merge is needed. Since current build job will be relaunched after rebase/merge happened in Gerrit, it is not necessary to make an useless build at this time.

Comment: How do you know, that a rebase/merge is needed on a petchset without submitting it? But verification needed for submitting. And the verification is made by your jenkins job, isn't it?

Comment: From my understanding, if current revision id is not same as git HEAD revision id, then a rebase/merge is needed for the patchset, right? Since anyway a rebuild is needed, current build should be skipped and just vote a "fail" for verification in Gerrit is enough.

Comment: if the patchset is fasforwardable or Gerrit can merge/rebase it itself then you dont get a new patchset for you change, it just simply merged after submitting. So a new patchset is created only if the merge is made on same file you modified.

Comment: How about un-fastforwardable patchset? Shouldn't we stop current build to save time?

Comment: So Gerrit should skip the verification if it detects that a rebase/merge will be needed - but I think this can not be detected - since this manually merge only happens if another change was submitted between the time when your patchset is created and trying to be submitted - but it means that the verification already started on your patchset

Answer (score 0):

After investigation I found out a way to detect potential merge conflict. A windows based shell script looks like below:

```
git fetch
git merge-base HEAD origin/master > _base
set /p MERGEBASE=<_base
git merge-tree %MERGEBASE% HEAD origin/master | grep -E -A3 "changed in both">_tempDiff
cat _tempDiff
set /p VAR=<_tempDiff
if not "%VAR%"=="" (
      echo "Your change needs rebase"
      exit /b -1
)
exit /b 0
```

If running this script at the very first of Gerrit verification build, the build will be broken immediately when current branch modifies same file with the latest master branch, which usually user has to rebase in Gerrit after build.